# How to use swingx in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, swingx, gui-builder

I have downloaded `swingx-all-1.6.4.jar` from [java.net swingx downloads](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases)

I want to use the components inside this library as components on `Palette` window of `Netbeans 7.4`. I mean I want to **drag&drop** `swingx` components like other `swing` companents in `Netbeans 7.4` IDE.
Is it possible to do that? 

**EDIT:**
I follow the instructions in this [link](http://fullofriddles.com/install-swingx-in-netbeans-7-3-1/), now I have components on the palette window. But some of the components are seen with default icon (question mark icon). Besides, I can use them too with drag&drop. I suspect that some of the components or files are missing or corrupted. Still working on it...

Comment: the current version is 1.6.5-1 - you can get it via maven.java.net. Yes, you need the beaninfo.jar (also available via maven) and install it in the palette

Comment: @kleopatra i downloaded `swingx-all-1.6.5.1.jar`, `swingx-beaninfo-1.6.5.1.jar`. In platte manager i clicked "**Add from JAR...**" then i added `swingx-beaninfo` file to the platte. Many companents appear in the platte but with questionmark icon. I also added `swingx-all-1.6.5.1.jar` file to my project by "**Add Library**". When i drag&drop added companents from platte it shows error message saying that "**cannot load companent class....**". Do i miss something?

Comment: sorry, can't help you with the details. Personally, I never use builders ;-) Did you search this site? There are probably similar questions, hopefully with answers.